# C# Equivalent of VB String Greater Than

Tags: c#, vb6, string-comparison, vb6-migration

Have an old vb6 project that is being rewritten in C# and a function has the following code:

```
If (strPlainChar >= "A" And strPlainChar <= "Z") Then
```

But obviously C# if statement won't allow a greater than on a string, how can I recreate this code?

Comment: "obviously", you say. However, you didn't even try. Had you done so, you would see it does allow it.

Comment: Just use characters instead of strings.

Comment: @Oded You cannot use `<=` etc. on `string`s in C#. It only works with `char`s.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Yes, though the VB6 is plainly dealing with characters , not whole strings.

Comment: @Oded Why the need to be so rude? A simple comment such as CodesInChaos of "just use characters instead of strings" is a much more constructive and helpful comment.

Comment: Well, we get many, many, many questions that show 0 effort here. This appeared to be one such question. You have not explained what exactly you have tried - you posted no C# code (failing or otherwise) or error messages from your failed attempts.

Comment: So because you felt it lacked effort you felt it was your right to be rude? I don't think being a moderator gives you the right to judge the users.

Comment: I do think you need to grow a thicker skin, if you want to interact on the Internet with others. I don't consider what I said to be rude - abrupt, maybe, but not rude. And for judging - I was judging the question and its quality, not you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `strPlainChar` consists only of a single character, you would use [the `char` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x9h8tsay.aspx) instead of `string`:

```
char strPlainChar = 'G';

if (strPlainChar >= 'A' && strPlainChar <= 'Z')
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`String.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx) method to compare strings:

```
strPlainChar.CompareTo("A") >= 0 &&  strPlainChar.CompareTo("Z") <= 0
```

Or if these are just characters, you can use the standard comparison operators:

```
strPlainChar >= 'A' &&  strPlainChar <= 'Z'
```

Comment: Wow, the only real correct answer, that didn't assumed anything and used the right method.

Comment: And it's subtly broken if you expect, say, `"Zoology"` to be within the range. So either you assume that `strPlainChar` consists only of a single letter, or I'd expect a comment in the code that points out that this behaviour is intentional.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do something like this:

```
char c = strPlainChar[0];
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
```

But I think this is a little more idiomatic for C#:

```
if (char.IsLetter(strPlainChar, 0) && char.IsUpper(strPlainChar, 0))
```

Comment: @CodesInChaos True: but I'd put that down as likely a **bug** in the original code. Of course, I can't say that for certain, but I expect this is probably more correct. If it would make you feel better, I could expand the answer to include more info on the difference.